# Facebook Javascript SDK FB not defined

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get error `FB not defined` when using Facebook Javascript SDK

```
FB.init({
    appId: '{APP ID}',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bl_praveen2004/XK3NZ/1/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things-

1. I can't see the JS SDK been loaded.
2. You have to call your `FB` functions after the SDK is loaded asynchronously, else it will throw that `FB is not defined`

So, to fix it-

```
// This will be triggered automatically after the SDK is loaded successfully
// write your FB fucntions inside this
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
     appId: '{app-id}',
     status: true,
     cookie: true,
     xfbml: true
   });

   FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
     if (response.status === 'connected') {
        GetData();
     } else {
        Login();
     }
  });
};

// JS SDK - this will be loaded asynchronously
(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function Login() {
   ...
   ...
}

function GetData() {
   ...
   ...
}
```

[Reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart)

**Edit:**

I saw that you are requesting for the permission `email` and yet not using it. Use the actual email (not the facebook one) with- `response.email`

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle still I see the function window.fbAsyncInit is not called

Comment: I am listing facebook friends email id. It does not show anything

Comment: I'm getting the result in console. Aren't you getting anything in console? not even any error? Another thing- use that with a valid url, you are using the jsfiddle url which is not configured in the app settings, so you must be getting error: "Giver URL is not ....."

Comment: No I am not getting any result in console. fbAsyncInit function is not called. I put an alert and tested. It is not called at all

Comment: In fiddle i can see error "Given URL is.." because in app settings you have not configured the site url to `jsfiddle.....`

Comment: The url that you are executing for the app, must be mentioned in the app settings `SITE URL`. PS, I'm getting the results properly!

Comment: I am working on localhost.Cannot I work in localhost?

Comment: So dont expect any result in jsfiddle. Write in the site url: `localhost/my_app` and run in your browser `localhost/myapp` and you'll see the result. Its very straight forward, I cant understand why are you stucked on this!

Comment: I have added the site url http://localhost:12001/test/facebook/chat/chatmessage.html to the API settings. Still the connect.facebook is not loaded

Comment: I've already explained the simple steps, please check your settings properly and see what error its showing in console

Comment: I have added the socail plugin blocker addon on the browser it was blocking facebook request. Now it is working Thanks very much